# What is gravitational radiation?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, terminology, radiation, gravitational-waves

What is gravitational radiation (in association with gravitational waves)? Is it a form of energy/mass? Or is it just another word for gravitational waves?

Answer (score 4):

Just as electromagnetic radiation and electromagnetic waves are the same thing, gravitational radiation and gravitational waves are the same thing.

Both kinds of radiation/waves transport energy, momentum, and angular momentum.

In a quantum-mechanical treatment, both consist of massless particles (photons and graviton).

Comment: Do they propagate at the speed of light? If so how was that determined?

Comment: Light is just an electromagnetic wave with a frequency that our eyes can detect. All electromagnetic waves propagate at the same speed in vacuum, the speed of light. The fact that gravitational waves propagate at the same speed was confirmed when LIGO and light telescopes simultaneously detected two neutron stars merging.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking gravitational waves are a subset of gravitational radiation. Gravitational radiation could in principle be radiated as [solitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton), and while these can be constructed from gravitational waves by Fourier synthesis we wouldn't normally describe them as a gravitational wave.

However this is a somewhat trifling objection and for all practical purposes you can use the two terms interchangeably.