# How do gravitational waves carry energy/radiation?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, radiation, gravitational-waves

How are gravitational waves related to gravitational radiation? How does gravitational radiation carry radiation/energy? What is it from?

Comment: Partial, hand-wavy answer; I'll leave it up to a relatively (as it were) more educated person to give a more technical answer.  Gravitational waves **are** gravitational radiation, or perhaps they are the mechanism by which gravity radiates.

Comment: But what is that radiation? Where is it from?

Comment: *How are gravitational waves related to gravitational radiation?* You [already asked this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/522626/what-is-gravitational-radiation), and I already answered. Why are you asking again?

Comment: Gravitational waves are ripples in the geometry of spacetime. They come from accelerating masses, such as the Earth orbiting the Sun. This is similar to how electromagnetic waves come from accelerating charges. There are differences which not explainable in a short comment.

Comment: What about the other 2? I just don't get it. Does this mean that space time is a propagor of radiation?

Comment: The other 2 *what*?

Comment: Yes, spacetime by itself can propagate gravitational waves.

Comment: Forget it. So are you saying gravity is radiation, gravitational waves is a propagation of radiation?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. This is what your saying - when spacetime propagates, radiation is created from it.

Comment: No, I am *not* saying that “gravity is radiation”. Gravitational waves are *not* what hold you to the surface of the Earth. And spacetime doesn’t propagate; it already exists everywhere. But ripples in spacetime’s geometry *can* propagate, and these are gravitational waves.

Comment: I’m being told to avoid an extended discussion in comments, so I’m done.